# Unix deleting subfolders with names in YYYYMMDD that are older than 30 days

Tags: unix, subdirectory, rm

I'm looking for simple line of code (if possible) to delete subfolders with names in YYYYMMDD that are older than 30 days. I have searched for some related solutions online and came up with this. I'm sure there's something I'm missing here because when I submitted this, no subfolders that are older than 30 days are deleted and not getting errors either.

`find /my/directory -type d -name '[0-9]{8}' -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: the `-name` option doesn't honor regex. It uses file-globbing rules, so `-name '[0-9][0-9].....'` . I'd be careful about that `rm` command, and confirm that it is working with `find ... -exec echo rm -rf {}` . After carefully examining all of that output, then redirect to shell, i.e. `find.... |bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `-regex` flag in find.

```
find /my/directory -type d -regex "[0-9]{8}" -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```